# Dog coughs all day and all night because of eating dirt

Tags: health

Our dog is a 13 year old Boykin spaniel-a year ago he started eating dirt non stop- tried muzzles- staying outside with him- you turn your back and he is eating dirt as fast as he can.the coughing is getting to be every hour in the hour- and have tried everything? We need some help please- he is miserable as well as ourselves.

Comment: Ask your vet -- it's possible you have that backward and he's eating dirt because he isn't feeling well...

Comment: Yes, go to the vet. This may be something serious. Depending on where you live, it could be heartworms, kennel cough, ...